# Getting error while importing a file to Marklogic from local

Tags: marklogic

I am trying to do a import of a xml file from my local system to Marklogic.
Its giving me an error that the its unable to connect to the Host on which Marklogic is runnning.
I have checked in the Marklogic admin console that the hostname is correct and its UP.
I am using below mlcp command to push the file.

```
mlcp.bat import -host owc-db01.owc.com -port 7998 -username admin -password admin@123 -input_file_path /E:/Shipment/Shipment/CBE00030166N.xml
```

I am getting this error -

```
22/04/20 11:20:58 DEBUG contentpump.ContentPump: Command: IMPORT
22/04/20 11:20:58 DEBUG contentpump.ContentPump: Arguments: -host owc-db01.owc.com -port 7998 -username admin -password ... -input_file_path /E:/Shipment/Shipment/CBE00030166N.xml
22/04/20 11:20:58 DEBUG contentpump.ContentPump: Running in: localmode
22/04/20 11:20:58 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: Content type is set to MIXED.  The format of the  inserted documents will be determined by the MIME  type specification configured on MarkLogic Server.
22/04/20 11:20:58 INFO contentpump.ContentPump: Job name: local_1613474636_1
22/04/20 11:20:58 INFO contentpump.FileAndDirectoryInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
22/04/20 11:20:58 DEBUG contentpump.CombineDocumentInputFormat: Total # of splits: 1
22/04/20 11:20:58 DEBUG contentpump.CombineDocumentInputFormat: Total # of combined splits: 1
22/04/20 11:20:59 ERROR contentpump.ThreadManager: Connection refused: connect
com.marklogic.xcc.exceptions.ServerConnectionException: Connection refused: connect
        at com.marklogic.xcc.impl.handlers.AbstractRequestController.runRequest(AbstractRequestController.java:153) ~[marklogic-xcc-10.0.9.jar:?]
        at com.marklogic.xcc.impl.SessionImpl.submitRequestInternal(SessionImpl.java:495) ~[marklogic-xcc-10.0.9.jar:?]
        at com.marklogic.xcc.impl.SessionImpl.submitRequest(SessionImpl.java:490) ~[marklogic-xcc-10.0.9.jar:?]
        at com.marklogic.contentpump.ThreadManager.queryServerMaxThreads(ThreadManager.java:143) [mlcp-10.0.9.jar:?]
        at com.marklogic.mapreduce.MarkLogicOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(MarkLogicOutputFormat.java:95) [mlcp-10.0.9.jar:?]
        at com.marklogic.contentpump.LocalJobRunner.run(LocalJobRunner.java:126) [mlcp-10.0.9.jar:?]
        at com.marklogic.contentpump.ContentPump.runJobLocally(ContentPump.java:356) [mlcp-10.0.9.jar:?]
        at com.marklogic.contentpump.ContentPump.runCommand(ContentPump.java:255) [mlcp-10.0.9.jar:?]
        at com.marklogic.contentpump.ContentPump.main(ContentPump.java:74) [mlcp-10.0.9.jar:?]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_311]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_311]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_311]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_311]
        at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_311]
        at com.marklogic.xcc.impl.SocketPoolProvider.obtainConnection(SocketPoolProvider.java:93) ~[marklogic-xcc-10.0.9.jar:?]
        at com.marklogic.xcc.impl.handlers.AbstractRequestController.runRequest(AbstractRequestController.java:89) ~[marklogic-xcc-10.0.9.jar:?]
        ... 8 more
22/04/20 11:20:59 WARN mapreduce.MarkLogicOutputFormat: Unable to connect to owc-db01.owc.com to query destination information
22/04/20 11:20:59 DEBUG mapreduce.MarkLogicOutputFormat: java.io.IOException: com.marklogic.xcc.exceptions.ServerConnectionException: Connection refused: connect
 [Session: user=admin, cb={default} [ContentSource: user=admin, cb={none} [provider: address=owc-db01.owc.com/10.10.1.8:7998, pool=0/64]]]
 [Client: XCC/10.0-9]
22/04/20 11:20:59 DEBUG contentpump.LocalJobRunner: Error checking output specification:
java.io.IOException: Unable to query destination information, no usable hostname found
        at com.marklogic.mapreduce.MarkLogicOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(MarkLogicOutputFormat.java:112) ~[mlcp-10.0.9.jar:?]
        at com.marklogic.contentpump.LocalJobRunner.run(LocalJobRunner.java:126) [mlcp-10.0.9.jar:?]
        at com.marklogic.contentpump.ContentPump.runJobLocally(ContentPump.java:356) [mlcp-10.0.9.jar:?]
        at com.marklogic.contentpump.ContentPump.runCommand(ContentPump.java:255) [mlcp-10.0.9.jar:?]
        at com.marklogic.contentpump.ContentPump.main(ContentPump.java:74) [mlcp-10.0.9.jar:?]
```

Comment: You're connecting through port 7998 while console is on 8000, this might be an issue here. You may have 8000 port open, but others closed, check that.

Comment: Excellent, It worked after using 8000 . Thanks for your help.